# What is the field "Folio" in an accounting book for?

Tags: accounting

I am not sure is this a right place to ask this question here. I am currently running my own business, and using a traditional accounting book to record all the debited and credited amounts. I don't know what the field that named "Folio" is for.

*PS: Please do let me know if this question is not related to this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's used as a [reference column](http://pakaccountants.com/folio-coloumn-use/):

> In journals folio coloumn is used to mention the reference or
>   “address” of ledger in which the journal entry has been posted thus
>   giving an easy access and also easily understanding whether all the
>   entries has been posted in the relevant accounts or not.